# Backbone.js DOM elements references approach

Tags: design-patterns, dom, backbone.js, reference, element

I'm currently building a large backbone app, and here is my question. How to cope with DOM elements refernces the best way? Now I simply find all elements which will be accessed in a future (forms and things like that) in my view's initialize function, and bind them to the view itself. This way I don't have to search for these elements every time I need to interact with them. But number of this references is growing quite quickly actually. Is it good approach or can I do better? Thanks in advance :)

Code example:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.form1 = this.$el.find('.whatever');
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yea I do the same thing...you should probably simplify your views if you have too many DOM element references per view

Answer (score 1):

After applying `$use` method `.selector` will be cached.

HTML:

```
<div data-container>
    <div data-something>smthng</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '[data-container]',
    ui : {
        something : '[data-something]'
    },
    someFn : function () {
        this.$use(this.ui.something).css('background', '#999');
        return this;
    },
    $use : function (selector) {
        console.log(typeof this.ui[selector] === 'undefined' ? 'dom query' : 'already cached');
        var $selector = this.ui[selector] === selector ?
            this.ui[selector] :
            this.$(selector);

        return this.ui[selector] = $selector;
    }
});

new View().someFn().someFn().someFn();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/K7nmr/